# How do you place a breakpoint inside a python package?

Tags: python, pandas, debugging

I'm working on contributing open source to the pandas package inside python. When I run import pandas as pd, it points to the installed version of python.

Wondering the best way to import the local version of the pandas library that I forked from github and set break-points inside to understand how the different functions work.

Comment: if you run it in an IDE, without installing it you can add breakpoints inside your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the **pdb-module**, using it for break-points goes as simple as:

```
 import pdb # import the module
 pdb.set_trace() # set break-point & open interactive shell
```

you can use the `set_trace` method whereever you want in any **Python script** you'd like to **debug**.

Here's a link to the official docs:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html